# Chi square distribution when $n=1$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, sampling, chi-squared

The PDF of $X \sim \chi^2(n)$ distribution is

$$ P(\chi^2) = \frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{2^{n/2}} \, \exp(-x/2) x^{n/2-1}. $$

In this PDF, for $n=2$ :-

\begin{align*}
P(\chi^2)
&= \frac{\Gamma(2/2)}{2^{2/2}} \, \exp(-x/2) x^{2/2-1} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(1)}{2}\, \exp(-x/2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \exp(-x/2),
\end{align*}

which is the PDF of exponential with mean $2$.

And my problem is :-

Normal distribution is a particular case of $\chi^2$-distribution when $n=1$, since for $n=1$,

$$ P(\chi^2) = \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{2^{1/2}} \, \exp(-x/2) x^{1/2-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, \exp(-x/2) x^{-1/2}. $$

But extra $1/\sqrt{x}$ term is there in the equation and it is not a standard normal distribution PDF.

How to get it with $n=1$ from chi-square distribution PDF.

If there anything wrong in my calculations then correct me.

Comment: [`$\link$`=$\link$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). MathJax tutorial.

Comment: The case $n=1$ of the $\chi^2$ distribution is the distribution of the *square* of a standard normal r.v., not of a standard normal r.v.

Answer (score 1):

The normal distribution is **not** a special case of the chi-squared distribution. What *is* true is that if $Z$ is standard normal, then $Z^2$ is chi-squared with $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct and confirms the fact that ChiSquared(m) $\equiv$ Gamma(m/2, 1/2). For this case, ChiSquared(1)=Gamma(1/2, 1/2), which has pdf

$$\frac{\left(\frac 12\right)^{1/2}}{\Gamma(1/2)}e^{-1/2 x}x^{1/2-1}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 x}x^{-1/2}$$

Note that it is not just the extra $x^{-1/2}$ term but the $x$ in the exponential is not squared as in the normal pdf.

Comment: Yeah this follow gamma pdf, but in my book P(χ2)=1/2^(n/2)*Γ(n/2) exp(-χ2/2) (χ2)^n/2-1 and for n=1, the equation becomes 1/√2π exp(χ2/2)χ^-1 ,then χ is squared in the exponential. And there is no steps written down in the book,they just directly write this is a standard normal distribution and χ is standard normal variate. I have just assume χ2=x for my convenience According to book, if we solve (χ2)^1/2-1 becomes χ^-1 for n=1. But extra χ^-1 term is not makes it normal pdf, which I already knew.but I don't understand the book's logic. Then how χ is a standard normal variate?

Comment: @SupriyaGorai p($\chi^2)=1/\sqrt{2\pi} \exp(-\chi^2/2)(\chi^2)^{-1/2}$. You can't mix the square in $\chi^2$ with the other exponents because you have to treat $\chi^2$ as one entity. Then if you replace $\chi^2=x$ you get $p(x)=1/\sqrt{2\pi} \exp(-x/2)x^{-1/2}$. Also, the square root of a chi squared random variable is called chi with *m* degrees of freedom. But a chi distribution with 1 df is not a standard normal distribution, even though a standard normal squared is chi squared with 1 df.

Comment: Yup I have got the point.

Comment: @SupriyaGorai are you going to accept the answer?